# Is there any need to include some fonts in head or are they default?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

For my own case, is there any need to add the Roboto font as a link in the `head` tag or is already default in Chrome?

I'm interested only for Chrome.

Comment: Why not make a test page to try it? It'd be like 10 lines long max.

Comment: Do you only want it to work on Chrome?

Comment: I did and from what I noticed there is no need to add it, jut that I didn't find anything official on the internet.

Comment: @Guy Incognito, I'm building with Electron, so yes

Comment: So what you really want to know is if Roboto is included in Electron.

Comment: This [link](https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults) shows all the default fonts that each browser uses

Comment: No, I wonder if the Roboto font is installed and understood by default by the Chrome browser, without the need to add it manual.

Comment: Chrome does not have fonts embedded in it nor does it install fonts along with the browser. Roboto is a separate font and is only available on Android systems. You can use web font technology to reference the font on web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't install fonts they just reference what's available. **Available** being the keyword is different depending on the OS & Device the browser runs on.

Chrome on an Android device will likely have access to Roboto as Google uses it heavily for Material. However, Roboto is not installed by default on most desktop operating systems or iOS unless the user has made a choice to do so.

**If you want to guarantee any font to be available you need to include it in your package or reference the font from a CDN** like fonts.google.com

Comment: That's why I've raised this question. So far I have not been able to reach a consensus, most of the answers being different. For example as you said, it should be included to be available for any device, but here for example(https://websitesetup.org/web-safe-fonts-html-css/) , Robot font is marked as a Web Safe Font

Comment: The only fonts available by default are system fonts. System fonts are different on every OS. **Roboto is ONLY a system font on Android and therefore NOT a web-safe font.**

Comment: @GeorgianStan Roboto is not mentioned on that page, other than in the comments (which you should take with a grain of sand). Besides, the article itself only mentions Windows fonts, so I assume when the author says "web safe", they actually mean "available to most desktop users".